# datagram packet receive buffer size -java

Tags: java, udp, buffer, datagram

I have tried receiving the datagram packet with the fixed buffer size and then would like to adjust it according to receive packet. I can get the actual buffer size of received packet but when i write it into the another buffer with the adjusted size it changes or grow its size again. How could it be even possible. I expect it to throw array out of bound exception.

```
byte[] recvbuffer=new byte[1024];
byte[] databuf=new byte[k-8];
byte[] checksumbuf=new byte[8];

recvpacket[i]=new DatagramPacket(recvbuffer,recvbuffer.length);
sock.receive(recvpacket[i]);
System.out.println(new String(recvbuffer));//1

int k=recvpacket[i].getLength();//k=28
System.out.println(k);

byte[] buffer=new byte[k];//buffer of size 28
System.out.println(buffer.length);
buffer=recvbuffer;
//buffer=recvpacket[i].getData();
System.out.println(new String(buffer));//buffer of size 1024, but how?
System.out.println(buffer.length);//
```

Answer (score 2):

Don't do this. Just set it to the largest expected datagram size plus one. Then, if you get one that size, it was a protocol error (and might have been even bigger).

When you process a received `DatagramPacket`, you should use its *actual* length via `DatagramPacket.getLength().` For example, your

```
System.out.println(new String(recvbuffer));//1
```

should be

```
System.out.println(new String(recvpacket[i].data(), 0, recvpacket[i].getLength()));
```

Comment: i get the length of the packet as packet.getLength(); But my question is how can i write the buffer in to new buffer of defined size. should i write it like byte[] buf=new byte[recvpacket[i].getLength()+1]

Comment: More or less, apart from the spurious +1, but why? Normally you would wrap a `ByteArrayInputStream` around the packet data, and probably a `DataInputStream` around that, and get the data out via various forms of `readXXX()` method. No second byte array required.